# Openpyxl : Error message at the opening of the .xlsx created from a WorkBook that used wb.remove_sheet(ws)

Tags: python, openpyxl, xlsx

**Situation:** I have `model.xlsx`, I delete 1 page, I save as `output.xlsx`. The page that I suppress have an image. There is no error raised.

**Problem:** when I try to open the file `output.xlsx` I have a first error message:
[image: Error message].

(*Sorry: We have found a problem in the file <<output.xlsx>> but we can try to get back the maximum. If the source of the classifier reliable, click On Yes.*)

And when I click on yes:
[image: Error message 2]
It says that it repaired the recording and it talks about images (so I suppose the images are the problem).

Then I have tricky errors (it delete the page but one other page that I try to duplicate doesn't keep track of the image).

**Solution:** I stopped using `wb.remove_sheet(ws)`, now I use `ws.sheet_state = 'hidden'` and it works like a charm ! No problem to duplicate page with image and no error message at the openning of the file.

But it's system D ! (I want to delete the page, not hide it and pretend I did the job).
Am I doing something wrong ? Is this an error coming from the openpyxl library ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer:** System D because nobody answer, don't del it, just hide it.